# Capybara/Selenium/Chrome not able to change value of select drop-down

Tags: html, ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

When I run my test with the features, steps, and HTML below the test executes without error (until it fails on the assertion steps), but I can see that no change occurs to the drop-down selects.  What am I doing wrong?

#### HTML:

```
<div class='field'> 
  <label for="verification_value">Verification Number</label> 
  <input id="verification_value" type="text" /> 
</div> 
<div class='field'> 
  <label for="month">Month</label> 
  <select id="month"> 
    <option value="1">1 - January</option> 
    <option value="2">2 - February</option> 
    <option value="3">3 - March</option> 
    <option value="4">4 - April</option> 
    <option value="5">5 - May</option> 
    <option value="6">6 - June</option> 
    <option value="7">7 - July</option> 
    <option value="8">8 - August</option> 
    <option value="9">9 - September</option> 
    <option value="10">10 - October</option> 
    <option value="11">11 - November</option> 
    <option value="12">12 - December</option> 
  </select> 
 </div>
```

#### step:

```
When /^(?:|I )select "([^"]*)" from "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, field|
  select(value, :from => field)
end
```

#### feature:

```
Feature: In order for this to work, a select menu should be changeable

    @javascript
    Scenario: A user follows the steps to successfully do fun stuff
        Given I go to a  page
        And I fill in "verification_value" with "12345"
        And I select "2 - February" from  "month"
        Then I should see "everything worked" within "body"
```

`And I select "2" from  "month"` doesn't actually produce any errors, it just doesn't change the select option.  It should be setting the select to `2 - February`

I also tried it with the firefox driver, and I get the same result

#### Update

Concerning the regex I added a `puts` line, and it was indeed ran

```
When /^(?:|I )select "([^"]*)" from "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, field|
  puts "STEP MATCHED"   # << it did put "STEP MATCHED"
  select(value, :from => field)
end
```

I copied that from the default `web_steps.rb` so I'm surprised it's not working for some people, but works fine for me.

Comment: Is Cucumber actually invoking that step?  When I tried with the code you supplied, it didn't match the regex, skipped the step, and suggested I create a step with the regex `/^I select "([^"]*)" from  "([^"]*)"$/`.  When I did that, it worked as expected.

Comment: Just to rule it out - are you _100% sure_ that the value is not getting set?  Could it be the step afterwards that is broken?  I'd be inclined to grab a screenshot _after_ the `select` call, or just a `sleep` to give you ample time to see what's happening in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an extra double quote in the SELECT tag. That may be causing the problem.

Comment: That was a typo on my post, the code only has the right quotes...good catch though

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried your code, and I don't really have time to right now, but you might consider testing that regular expression.  If you're trying to avoid requiring the "I" in that step definition, I'd recommend doing this:

```
When /^(?:I )?select "([^"]*)" from "([^"]*)"$/ do |value, field|
  select(value, :from => field)
end
```

The question-mark after a capture group (denoted by parentheses) implies that the contents of the capture group is optional.  That might help it identify the step if the prior answer is any indication as to why it's not working.

Comment: Thanks @SeanMeh, but the regex isn't the problem, see me update.